# The relation $ A^2B = BA^2 $ from $ \langle A,B | A^4 = I , B^2 = I , BA =A^{-1}B \rangle $

Tags: group-theory, permutations

An article on [Group theory](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/groups/CHAP01%20Introduction%20to%20Groups.pdf)(p.9) says that "we could deduce any relation of that given permutation from the presentation of that permutation". The presentation of the permutation given in the article is 
$$ \langle A,B | A^4 = I , B^2 = I , BA =A^{-1}B \rangle. $$
Even though that presentation might be true I can't deduce the relation $ A^2B = BA^2 $.

Comment: $$ABA=B\implies A^2B=(A^2B)A^4=A(ABA)A^3=ABA^3=(ABA)A^2=BA^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that:
\begin{align*}
BA^2 & = (BA)A \\
& = (A^{-1}B)A,\quad &&BA=A^{-1}B \\
& = A^3BA,\quad &&A^4 = I\implies A^3 = A^{-1} \\
& = A^3(A^{-1}B),\quad &&BA = A^{-1}B \\
& = A^2 B
\end{align*}

If we want to start with the presentation:
\begin{align*}
BA & = A^{-1}B \\
BAA & = A^{-1}BA,&&\text{right multiply by }A \\
BA^2 & = A^3BA, &&A^4=I\implies A^{-1} = A^3 \\
BA^2 & = A^3 (A^{-1}B), && BA = A^{-1}B \\
BA^2 & = A^2 B
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you show the same answer starting from the presentation of the permutation instead of starting from the given relation.

Comment: Could you tell why for particular orders of the permutation , the given relation is commutative. For example in the given [article] (http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/groups/CHAP01%20Introduction%20to%20Groups.pdf) we could see that $ A^2B = BA^2 $ and $A^6B = BA^6 $ while AB != AB and $ A^3B != BA^3 $.

Comment: The general rule that's true (and is provable without too much trouble) is that $A^{-k}B = BA^k$.  This means that $A^{-2}B = BA^2$, but as $A^4 = I$ we have that $A^2 = A^{-2}$, so $A^2B = BA^2$.  For similar reasons, $A^6B = A^4(A^2B) = A^2B$, so this is precisely the same relation!  We can't expect $A^3B = BA^3$, as $A^{-3} = A$, so we instead have that $AB = BA^3$.

Comment: Could you tell how you got $ A^2B = BA^2 $ from $ A^2 = A^{-2} $. I tried but couldn't get it.

Comment: I got that from $A^2 = A^{-2}$, and from $A^{-k}B = BA^k$, by setting $k =2$.

Comment: Could you tell how you got $ A^{-k}B = BA^k $. I tried using $ A^{-1}B = BA $ but no hope to find it.

Comment: It's essentially just induction on that relation.  We have that $A^{-k}B = A^{-(k-1)}A^{-1}B = A^{-(k-1)}BA = A^{-(k-2)}A^{-1}BA = A^{-(k-2)}BA^2 = \dots$, repeated until you get $BA^k$.

Comment: Sorry you done it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67442/discussion-between-mark-and-justin).